# How to format 1D array data for a 1D CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am wondering how I can formate my data, a list of 1000 numeric features, into a shape that my 1D CNN will take in. Here is an [image of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CQ87.png)(it is in dataframe format - 1000 columns, 9923 rows) and my first layer of my CNN will be something like

```
model.add(Conv1D(64,3, activation ='relu', input_shape= (1000, 1)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input shape of the layer is (1000,1). That means the layer accepts any inputs of shape (*,1). So the last dimension of the input should be 1. You can **reshape** your data as example below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data=tf.Variable(np.random.random((9923,1000)),dtype=tf.float32) #your data has shape (9923,1000)
#print(data)
data=tf.reshape(data,(9923,1000,1)) #reshape data
#print(data)
conv1d=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64,3, activation ='relu', input_shape= (1000, 1)) # the layer accpets any input with shape (*,1). 
# That means the last dimention should be 1
cnn_data=conv1d(data) # output cnn_data has shape  (9923,998,64)
```

Comment: what is the cnn_data=conv1d(data) for?

Comment: It is an example of applying the layer on the data with new format. It shows what will be the shape of output of the layer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a 3D shape (9923, 1000, 1)

Check out my repo. I use 1D-CNN also but for time-series problems.
https://github.com/chasebk/EO_CNN

Comment: which file in your github is your cnn?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/chasebk/EO_CNN/blob/master/models/main/traditional_rnn.py

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26673002)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani, my answer to the question is the first line. He also confirms its work. The link below is just another suggestion.